# Autofilling fields in a new tab in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bots, autofill

Background: I'm new to Javascript, but did a lot of looking around and experimenting and have been a tad stuck.

The goal for this bit is simply to type a number on one page, click a button, then:

1. Open a new tab
2. Wait for the page to load
3. Fill the number in a corresponding field in the new tab
4. Click a button in new tab

Getting the input, opening tabs and waiting for it to load works a-ok, but I can't sort out how to get that input into the *new* tab, not the *original* tab.

Relevant bit (last line is problematic part):

```
inputNumber = document.getElementById('inputNumber').value;

var wdw1 = window.open("https://example.com", "win1");
                
wdw1.onload = wdw1.document.getElementById("search").value = inputNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but [`onload` should be a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).
You could try something like:

```js
wdw1.onload = function () {
  wdw1.document.getElementById("search").value = inputNumber;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Luke!  That's certainly a step in the right direction but unfortunately it's still not working; after trying several completely different sites, several different functions, and all sorts of variations and browsers, it works fine when operating on *document* but still never seems to recognize or operate on the new tab, *wdw1.document* :/

Comment: If windows share the same origin (host, port, protocol), then windows can do whatever they want with each other.

Otherwise, only possible actions are:
- Change the location of another window (write-only access).
- Post a message to it.

See: https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication